# Undo Dubious Tag [udt]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

There's a tag [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt) with about 97 questions; there's no tag wiki; over 50% of the questions are unanswered; the tag has 6 followers (I wonder if they know what they're following?); only one of the top answerers has more than one answer in the tag; the asker with the most questions has managed three questions with the tag for two upvotes; and the top asker has one question with 9 upvotes).

The questions seem to be all over the place.

- Some are referring to 'user defined type' in a database.
- Some seem to be referring to a dialect of C, or perhaps to UDP networking.
- Some seem to be referring to a library from Sourceforge.
- Some seem to be referring to Python; others to C#.
- …and that's just the first page and a casual glance.

If I was going to keep the tag, I'd give it the meaning of 'user defined type' in a DBMS and remove the tag from questions on other manifestation.

Should the tag be burninated?  Or revamped as a DBMS user defined type?  Or as something else?

#### Update

Since [Rhymoid](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/824425/rhymoid) [pointed out](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/310940/undo-dubious-tag-udt#comment275006_310940) that the tag [user-defined-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-types) (plural) exists, it was simple to retag a large number of the questions previously tagged [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt) with [user-defined-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-types) (sometimes it was just a question of removing the [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt) tag).  I've put a provisional [Wiki entry](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/udt/info) for [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt) that mainly suggests using [user-defined-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-types) and not using [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt).

- Is it sensible to suggest making [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt) into a synonym for [user-defined-types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/user-defined-types)?
- Those changes leave something like 28 questions still tagged with [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt).  Many of these are referring to the [UDP-based Data Transfer](http://udt.sourceforge.net/) (UDT) library. Is it appropriate to make the [udt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt) tag refer to this, or should a new tag be created such as [udp-data-transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udp-data-transfer), [udp-based-data-transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udp-based-data-transfer) or perhaps [udt-library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/udt-library), along with an appropriate Wiki entry that identifies what it is about and referencing the library on Sourceforge, etc.  I note that the UDT library has not been updated since 2011, and the related [Sector/Sphere](http://sector.sourceforge.net/) project which is cross-referenced on the UDT page has likewise not been updated since then.

Comment: I think people are confusing [tag:udp] and [tag:udt] somehow. For DBMS-related questions, the tag [tag:user-defined-type] already exists. There's also ["UDP-based Data Transfer"](http://udt.sourceforge.net/), which is the subject of probably the only question with an appropriate [tag:udt] tag. I'd support burnination.

Comment: @Rhymoid:  Thanks. I agree that at least some of the confusion was UDP vs UDT.  The Sourceforge UDT library is interesting, but apparently hasn't been updated since 2011 (but was actively developed 2006-2011).  If there's already [tag:user-defined-type] then there's clearly no need for [tag:udt] for the same task; I can go ahead and retag or untag those [tag:udt] questions with a clear conscience.  Then there can be a reassessment of what's left over.

Comment: The existing tag for database UDTs is [tag:user-defined-types] (plural, not singular).